# How to access created nodes in a mininet topology?

Tags: python, mininet, pox

I am new in mininet. I created a custom topology with 2 linear switches and 4 nodes. I need to write a python module accessing each nodes in that topology and do something but I don't know how.

Any idea please?

Comment: see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following:

s1.cmd('ifconfig s1 192.168.1.0')

h1.cmd('ifconfig h1 192.168.2.0')

Comment: Thank you, it is good but the problem is that i want to generate some packets by using scapy. in fact a topology is created an each node has to send some TCP packets and i have no idea how to do that.